# How to publish a Report to SharePoint 2013 Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, service, reporting

I have created a report using SQL Server Data Tool 2008, and I want to publish this report to a Document Library on Site SharePoint(2013).

When I try to deploy the solution, I get this error[image: ERROR]

Please help if you have any solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually on SharePoint 2010 or 2013? I see both mentioned in your post.

Can you confirm whether or not your SSRS working fine in integration mode or not? Are other reports working fine? Have you upgraded recently?

If this is a test environment you could try either to [upgrade](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/792992d8-661c-4875-8bf8-393c24c61640/upgrading-sharepoint-integrated-mode-from-sql-2008-r2-to-sql-2012?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) or [re-create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468182/version-of-report-server-database-is-either-in-a-format-that-is-not-valid-or-it) the reporting services service application (pointing to the existing database) as per the links.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi BlueSky2010! I'm using SharePoint 2013. This is a first time I use SSRS and this report is the first report I've created.I have re-create SSRS on SP2013 Server but when I re-deploy, I still get this error. Thanks you anyway :)

Comment: Have you checked the SharePoint ULS logs if you can find anymore details? Default path is - C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS